# Question about a biological process as opposed to medical practice

Tags: discussion, support, scope, moderation, specific-question

Why is my [question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/seboorrheic-dermatitis-fungi-environmental-factors) a typical clinical question as AliceD [said](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/why-was-my-question-migrated-to-medical-science#comment6122_4078)?

I asked about the condition in itself and its causes and not about its treatment/prevention/hygiene( medical practice is only secondary to my question).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking here. We can't explain Chris' and AliceD's reasoning. But I must say that when you ask why clinicians believe something, that does make your question at least somewhat clinical.

Comment: @CareyGregory I didn't ask why the AAD believes it I asked why and how it is true. They just happened to assert something that I can't understand/ I am questioning its validity. I am not addressing the assertion per se I am addressing the content of the assertion. I could remove the reference to AAD's assertion without affecting the question.

Comment: @CareyGregory This meta question is not about AliceD's assertion either. It is about the content. The person does not matter the content of their assertion does. I actually tried to explain my point of view and thence draw an answer indirectly. Here I am trying to get the same answer directly( not why they asserted so by why is it true).

Comment: I think I understand your reasoning now, so what I would suggest is deleting your question and rewriting it such that it has a clear biology basis. I think the link to the AAD may be what led to the misunderstanding and unwanted migration. But you'll still need prior research, so you still need a link to something stating that hygiene isn't a cause/contributor. I think you could still use the AAD article, but you need to clarify better. And also see my comment on your question. I think your reasoning about bathing and weather is off the mark.